# The convertion of the boundry of double integral to polar form

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the boundry of this integral in polar form? The bounds of $x$ and $y$ are $(-\infty ,\lambda)$, I solve the first integral and I stopped. The integral is  $$A=\int\int r e^{-\dfrac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}r^2(1-2\rho\cos\theta\sin\theta)}dr d\theta.$$The solution is like this$$A=\int \dfrac{-(1-\rho^2)}{(1-\rho\sin 2\theta)}e^{-\dfrac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}r^2(1-\rho\sin 2\theta)}\Bigg\vert d\theta$$but I don't know the bounds in polar form.

Comment: Is  $ \lambda   \geq  0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The following figure depicts the region of integration in terms of $x$ and $y$  if $\lambda>0$, and if    $\lambda = 0$.

[image]

---

The easiest case is when $\lambda=0$, then the bounds of integration are $\pi\le \theta\le \frac32\pi$ and $0\le r\le \infty$.

---

If $\lambda>0$ then there are $3$ regions for $\theta$ we have to distinguish.

- $-\frac{\pi}2< \theta\le \frac{\pi}4$
- $\frac{\pi}4<\theta<\pi$
- $\pi<\theta<\frac32\pi\, (=-\frac{\pi}2)$

The third case is easy again. Here $\pi\le \theta\le \frac32\pi$ and $0\le  r<\infty.$

In the first case we have $r_{max}=\frac{\lambda}{\cos(\theta)}.$ So, the bounds are $-\frac{\pi}2< \theta\le \frac{\pi}4$ and $0\le r\le \frac{\lambda}{\cos(\theta)}$.

In the second case $r_{max}=\frac{\lambda}{\sin(\theta)}$...

**EDITED**

The OP answered Nizar's question. The OP reinforced that $\lambda\ge 0$. Then the OP's response disappeared.

Now, I have to get tbeck to the case $\lambda<0$. I just hope that based on my hint above the OP will solve the problem for $\lambda<0$. If not, then pls. make a related comment.

Comment: Thanks, with this hint I can solve this integral in other case.